# In Django 1.8, how can I set settings.py so that manage static files?

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

Code snippet managed static files in settings.py as follows.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__),
        'static',
    ),
]
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR + '/templates/'
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', [
                    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                ]),
            ],
            'debug' : True
        },
    },
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**url.py**file is as follows.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from tweets.views import Index, Profile
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', Index.as_view()),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^user/(\w+)/$', Profile.as_view()),
]
```

**views.py**file is as follows

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Django</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    <h1 class="text-info">Hello {{name}}!</h1>
    {% endblock %}
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run server, browser can't find *bootstrap.min.js* file.

> Page not found at /static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
>     http://localhost:8000/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
>     'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' could not be found

It seems that the static files url is correct.
But browser can't find the static files.
Please tell me the reason and how can I handle it?

Comment: Do you have created a path `static/project_name/boostrap.min.js` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To serve the static files [during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) you should add to your urls.py the following code:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from tweets.views import Index, Profile
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', Index.as_view()),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^user/(\w+)/$', Profile.as_view()),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

And you should create the path in your project folder `static/your_app/your_files`

Comment: Thanks for your help. but *name 'static' is not defined* exception has occurred. what is **static** & **STATIC_ROOT**? I'm beginner.

Comment: you need to add `from django.conf import settings` and
`from django.conf.urls.static import static` in your urls.py. It will define your static urls, STATIC_ROOT is the directory where you gonna server your static files.

Comment: I have added two modules and **STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static") in settings.py** but nothing has happened.

Comment: urls.py works well. but Browser can't find static files, such as bootstrap.min.js & bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Are you sure that you create the folllowing path in your project folder `static/your_app_name/your_file` and in  href="{% static 'your_app/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" ?

Comment: Where do I create the path in? settings.py file? What does the path mean, and where is the path located?

Comment: Please tell me how can I handle it. I have been doing it for over 2 hours. I'm going to be mad.

Comment: You need to create a folder inside your app folder named `static`, so inside this folder, you gonna create another folder with the same name of your project so the path will be `your_project_folder/static/your_app_name` and them you gonna put you static files there.  And follow the [documetation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Sure, I did it. I think there is a problem with http://localhost:8000/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css.